# Webpack 4 - file-loader - not rendered fonts with @font-face (but build and everything works fine)

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-file-loader

after upgrading webpack 2->4, the fonts are not rendered anymore on website (with file-loader, I also tried url-loader, but does not help). The build works fine, also @font-face loading in .styl does not cause any issues. When I look at network tab in dev-tools I also do not see fonts there - in old version of the app I see them.

Here are the configs:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const nib = require('nib');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
require('dotenv').config();

process.traceDeprecation = true;

const config = {
  entry: ['./src/main.js', './src/styles/scss/app.scss'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|otf|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /react-sortable-tree\/style\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:
          'style-loader!css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader?camelCase&modules&localIdentName=[local]',
          },
          {
            loader: 'stylus-loader',
            options: {
              use: [nib()],
              import: ['~nib/lib/nib/index.styl'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.styl'],
    enforceExtension: false,
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With',
    },
    port: 8082,
    setup: app => {
      require('dotenv').config();
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL),
        BASE_API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_API_URL),
        TEMPLATING_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.TEMPLATING_URL),
        USDA_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.USDA_API_KEY),
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_ID),
      },
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

base.styl (which gets loaded, because styles from it are applied)

```
/***** FONTS *****/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Bold';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/BrandonText/BrandonText-Bold.otf") format('opentype');
    /*font-weight: 600;*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Medium';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/BrandonText/BrandonText-Medium.otf") format('opentype');
    /*font-weight: 500;*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/BrandonText/BrandonText-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
    /*font-weight: 400;*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Regular';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/BrandonText/BrandonText-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
    /*font-weight: 400;*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Light';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/BrandonText/BrandonText-Light.otf") format('opentype');
    /*font-weight: 300;*/
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gellix-Bold';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/Gellix/Gellix-Bold.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gellix-BoldItalic';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/Gellix/Gellix-BoldItalic.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gellix-MediumItalic';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/Gellix/Gellix-MediumItalic.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gellix-Medium';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/Gellix/Gellix-Medium.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gellix-Regular';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/Gellix/Gellix-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gellix-RegularItalic';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/Gellix/Gellix-RegularItalic.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SFProText';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/SFPro/SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SFProText-Regular';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/SFPro/SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SFProText-Medium';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/SFPro/SF-Pro-Text-Medium.otf") format('opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SFProText-Bold';
    src: url("../../static/fonts/SFPro/SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf") format('opentype');
}

half-pixel-bottom(color)
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 50%, color 50%)
    background-size: 100% 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat


body {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'BrandonText';
}

*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

.do-not-display {
    display: none !important;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    min-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.page-item {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.half-pixel-bottom
    height: 1px
    width: 100%
    position: relative
    half-pixel-bottom(#d8d8d8)

.dash-underlined {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #bdc0c9;
}

.omg-green {
    color: #0eaf27;
}

.omg-green-link {
    color: #0eaf27;
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Medium';
    text-decoration: underline;
}
    .omg-green-link:hover {
        color: #0eaf27;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

.bold {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Bold';
}

.header-wrapper
    position fixed
    top 0
    background-color #fff
    width 100%
    z-index 9999

    .navbar
        box-shadow 0px 0px 5px 0px #ccc

.content-wrapper
    margin-top 80px

.scrollable
    &::-webkit-scrollbar 
        -webkit-appearance: none
        width: 6px
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
        border-radius: 4px
        background-color: rgba(146, 146, 146, 0.25)
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5)
```

And here how the build works normally:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your urls are not resolved for fonts. Because at the end user machine, it will try to look for static folder and gives 404.

```
  loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'static/[hash].[ext]',
                    emitFile: true,
                    esModule: false,
                }
```